# Why selective ring opening of the compound (attached image) by acid catalyst through results in a wide variety of branched iso-paraffins?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image: THE REACTANT COMPUND]

Basically, I want to know that why through beta scission, there is a possibility of formation of so many products, for example;
2-Ethyl-4-methylheptane;
2,4,6-Trimethylheptane;
2,2,5-Trimethylhexane;
3-Ethyl(2-methyl)hexane;
2,4-Dimethylhexane; 
2,4-Dimethylpentane.

Comment: typo error- there's no 'through' in the question statement